# Prove the Gaussian curvature $K=0$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning, curvature

> If two families of a geodesics on a surface intersect at a constant angle $\theta$, prove that the Gaussian curvature of the surface is zero, i.e. $K=0$.

Please explain how to show the question. Thank you for helping.

$K=k_1k_2$ for principal curvatures $k_1, k_2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider small parallelograms formed by these geodesics, and apply Gauss-Bonnet.

**EDIT:** Here's what I mean: Take two geodesics $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ from family A and two geodesics $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ from family B. Define points $P$, $Q$, $R$, and $S$ by taking $P=\gamma_1\cap\sigma_1$, $Q=\gamma_1\cap\sigma_2$, $R=\gamma_2\cap\sigma_2$, and $S=\gamma_2\cap\sigma_1$. (Draw a picture of all this.) Apply Gauss-Bonnet to this "parallelogram" formed by the pieces of the four geodesics joining $P$, $Q$, $R$, and $S$.

Comment: Please can you explain small parallelograms formed by these geodesics? I dont know this part? If you Will show here, I Will able to apply G-B theorem by myself. Thank you for helping.

Comment: No, Gauss-Bonnet is applied to the *region* $\mathscr R$ inside $PQRS$. Keep track of the four exterior angles. This should show $\iint_{\mathscr R} K\,dA=0$. Now how do you deduce $K=0$ everywhere?

Comment: Then Gaussian curvature should be constant. But I cannot see why this is equal to zero.

Comment: If I tell you $\int_a^b f(x)dx = 0$ for a continuous function $f$ and *all* intervals $[a,b]\subset\Bbb R$, how do you prove that $f=0$ everywhere?

Comment: Okay thank you, I understand:)

Comment: Yeah! This is actually a really cool problem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you know if this method, using Chern's version of Gauss-Bonnet, will generalize to higher (even) dimension and different types of foliations (e.g. different codimensions)? It's not immediately obvious to me, but I'm not experienced using the generalized formula.

Comment: @Neal: Chern proved a manifold-with-boundary formulation of his Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but I don't know of a simple manifold-with-corners version. Certainly, Allendoerfer-Weil and people like Cheeger have thought about polyhedral versions and Fu has done work with currents and normal cycles, which may well answer your question. I've never thought about it.

Comment: @Neal: By the way, totally geodesic foliations in dimension $>1$ are extremely rare. It's a good exercise to show that can happen only in spaces of constant curvature.